# tensorflow - multiply two vectors to produce a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two vectors like `row = [1,2,3,4]` `col = [0,1,2,3]` and I want to multiply them to produce a matrix:

```py
[
  [0,0,0,0],
  [1,2,3,4],
  [2,4,6,8],
  [3,6,9,12]
]
```

How can I do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to convert them to Tensorflow [`tf.constants`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) and then you can multiply them, using [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul):

```
a = tf.constant(row, shape=[4, 1])
b = tf.constant(col, shape=[1, 4])

result = tf.matmul(row,col)
```